# Mean of a imported file using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, matlab, file, import

I'm new using Visual Studio 2010, but I have some experience using MATLAB. I wrote the following code in MATLAB, which imports an excel file to estimate the mean of two variables:

```
Excel File, Sheet1:

Number     A       B
1          19      30
2          21      28
3          23      22
4          26      21
5          17      17
```

```
[FileName,PathName]=uigetfile({'*.xlsx;*.xls'},'Select file');
Data=importdata([PathName,FileName]);
A=Data.data.Sheet1(:,2);
B=Data.data.Sheet1(:,3);
X=mean(A);
Y=mean(B);
fprintf('X is %0.2f and Y is %0.2f',X,Y);
```

The expected results are:

```
X is 21.20 and Y is 23.60
```

How can I do the same but in Visual Studio 2010?

Best regards!

Comment: Visual Studio Code is an IDE. You should specify what language are you using, what have you tried and what's were the results. Consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting a question.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In my case, I'm trying to develop a "Windows Form Application". If I choose a button to do this, the default code is:                                              Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    End Sub
End Class